# Year check, update in text file using VBS

Tags: vbscript

Want to check if year is actual year in text file and update if not actual, 2013.
For example text line is: SET YEAR=2012
So far I have only been able to write actual year into file, but now I need to update the information in file if it exist...
Appreciating any help here.

```
dim filesys 
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
path = filesys.GetAbsolutePathName("C:\Backups\Machine.bat") 
getname = filesys.GetFileName(path) 
If filesys.FileExists(path) Then 
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFile("C:\Backups\Machine.bat") 
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Backups\Machine.bat", 8) 
    objFile.WriteLine 
    objFile.Write("SET YEAR=") 
    objFile.WriteLine(Year(Date())) 
    objFile.Close 
End if
```

Comment: Novice in this business...dim filesys
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
path = filesys.GetAbsolutePathName("C:\Backups\Machine.bat")
getname = filesys.GetFileName(path)
If filesys.FileExists(path) Then
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFile("C:\Backups\Machine.bat")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Backups\Machine.bat", 8)
objFile.WriteLine
objFile.Write("SET YEAR=")
objFile.WriteLine(Year(Date()))
objFile.Close
End if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace a particular line in a text file like this:

```
path = "C:\Backups\Machine.bat"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
If fso.FileExists(path) Then
  Set inFile  = fso.OpenTextFile(path)
  Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile(path & ".tmp", 2, True)
  Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
    line = inFile.ReadLine
    If UCase(Left(Trim(line), 9)) = "SET YEAR=" Then
      outFile.WriteLine "SET YEAR=" & Year(Date)
    Else
      outFile.WriteLine line
    End If
  Loop
  inFile.Close
  outFile.Close

  fso.DeleteFile path, True
  fso.MoveFile path & ".tmp", path
End If
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks. What if I want to remove duplicate "SET YEAR=2012" from the file, but still keep one line up to date?

Comment: @user3062778 You could skip over the lines starting with `SET YEAR=` (i.e. not write an output line for those input lines) and write `SET YEAR=2013` as the last line (after the loop has finished).

Comment: Thanks again. Now I have it doing the job.